# Match inflectional forms of words in a particular order with SQL Server full-text search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, sql-server-2016

I'd like to use [SQL Server full-text search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find inflectional forms of words that occur in a specific order.  So the words `method` and `apparatus` would match `These are the methods I'm using with the apparatuses` but not `This apparatus is used with these methods`.

Is there a way to do this?  It seems pretty simple, but I've found nothing.

I've tried `CONTAINS` with:

```
'NEAR((method,apparatus), MAX, TRUE) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,method) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,apparatus)'

'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,NEAR((method,apparatus), MAX, TRUE))'

'NEAR((FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,method),FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,apparatus)), MAX, TRUE)'
```

Comment: so in result set required does method occurs before apparatus in all scenarios?

Comment: Yes, correct...

Comment: So, you don't want to use CHARINDEX for performance issues, right?

Comment: Not clear. Can you explain why method and apparatus should appear in that order only and WHY "This apparatus is used with these methods" is wrong ? Can you give few more such example ?

Comment: @KumarHarsh  --- It should appear in that order if the person searching wants it to.  I want my application to provide the ability to search that way.  I don't really need a reason beyond that.  There is not "wrong", it's just the way the client would be using the application.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you cannot combine `FORMSOF` with `NEAR` (here is the [reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142568%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)). A possible way to do (though not efficient) is to try all the different alternatives of *'method'* and *'apparatus'* (if you don't have other words to search for), like the following:

```
   SELECT some_id
   FROM some_table
   WHERE CONTAINS(some_text, 'NEAR((method,apparatus), MAX, TRUE) OR NEAR((method,apparatuses), MAX, TRUE) OR NEAR((methods,apparatus), MAX, TRUE) OR NEAR((methods,apparatuses), MAX, TRUE)')
```

Another option is to use `CHARINDEX` (which could also be inefficient), like this:

```
   SELECT some_id
   FROM some_table
   WHERE CONTAINS(some_text, 'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,method) AND FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL,apparatus)')
   AND CHARINDEX('method', some_text) < CHARINDEX('apparatus', some_text)
```

They both worked fine with me. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Unfortunately, as you pointed out, it's not efficient and thus not workable in my case.

Comment: Well, at least it is working according to the simple example you provided in your question. Can you please post a sample of your data where my queries do not work? With respect to efficiency, your question clearly asks for any way to do it (no efficiency concerns!)